# Configurable Endpoints using CRest

Tags: java, android, rest

I'm trying to create an Android application that uses [CRest](http://crest.codegist.org/index.html) to interface with a RESTful web service.

The issue I am having is with the creation of a Service.  In the twitter examples the EndPoint is set to a static url (api.twitter.com) but in my case I need it to be configurable since we won't know the endpoint until the user specifies it.

What I would like to do is something along the lines of this:

```
@EndPoint("http://%s.somedomain.com")
@ContextPath("/admin")

public interface ProductService {
    @Path("/products.json")
    InputStream getProducts();

    @Path("/products/{0}.json")
    InputStream getProduct(int id);
}
```

Is there a way I can specify on the creation of the service where the EndPoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the [quick start](http://crest.codegist.org/quick-start.html) link, at the bottom you can find this piece of code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("service.end-point", "http://127.0.0.1:8080");

CRest crest = new CRestBuilder()
                        .overrideDefaultConfigWith(props)
                        .build();
```

Next release will have an easier way to do it, either through the Builder or through a convention with placeholders on annotation values as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

BTW the placeholder implementation is there and documented now http://crest.codegist.org/annotations/api.html

```
@EndPoint("http://{my.interface.host}")
public interface MyInterface {
    ...
}
```

Used with

```
String myInterfaceHost = ...;

CRest crest = CRest.placeholder("my.interface.host", myInterfaceHost).build();

MyInterface myInterface = crest.build(MyInterface.class);
```